# View the code of all the functions being called from within a function

Tags: python

Take the following functions:

```py
def alpha(a):
    return a**2

def beta(a):
    return alpha(a)+1
```

To view the source code of the `beta` function we can do:

```py
import inspect
inspect.getsource(beta)
```

---

**Question**:

How do I view the source code of `beta`, `alpha` and all the functions which are being called from `beta` if I know only that my function is named `beta`?

Answer (score 1):

So... go back to your initial post and put the functions into the interpreter directly.  Then:

```
for a in beta.__globals__:
   if callable(beta.__globals__[a]):
      print(a)
```

Note that there is a double underscore both before and after globals.
This will give you a list of functions callable by beta.  The **loader** function that shows up is not user defined, so you can ignore that (probably anything that starts and ends with double-underscore, for that matter).

Comment: I would like to be able to do this from within my JupyterLab / Notebook where I other functions too?

Comment: __globals__ should be there for any python method.  Using inspect you can change the if to "if inspect.isfunction(beta.__globals__[a]):" and it will do the same thing but only print the functions alpha and beta.  So it would be something like "for func in routine.__globals__: if inspect.isfunction(routine.__globals__[func]): print (func)" and as long as you have one known function you can iterate over all its known functions and their known functions, etc. by performing the same loop with the discovered routine name.

Comment: It outputs all the functions from within the notebook, I want only the ones called by `beta`.

Answer (score 0):

Save the two modules into a .py file (let's pick test.py as an example).
Now open an interactive python session and:

```
python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Sep 11 2019, 16:40:19)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> import inspect
>>> print (inspect.getsource(test.beta))
def beta(a):
    return alpha(a)+1

>>> print (inspect.getsource(test.alpha))
def alpha(a):
    return a**2
```

It won't work if you start python, then type in the functions as inspect needs to have the source code from whence the functions came.  The items available without the source are already compiled into bytecode, so wouldn't provide you with anything readable.

Comment: You don't know that there is such a function named `alpha`. Only by looking at `beta` you can see that there is another function which is being called (there might be more), in this case `alpha` and you should output the source code of `alpha` too.

Comment: well... you can do something like this:  for name in beta.__globals__:  print(name, beta.__globals__[name]) and see the functions listed.  That would be "test.beta" if you imported it from the file as above.

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'name' is not defined`,